# Link_to remote => true causing strange routing problems, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, post, link-to

I am having some problems with link_to remote sending a post to another controller... The result are not quite what I expect..

I have this in node_content.html.erb:

```
<% @node.videos.each do |vid| %>
 <div id="vid_vid"><%= link_to image_tag("http://img.youtube.com/vi/#{vid.content}/1.jpg"),  :controller => 'videos', :action => "iframize", :video_id => vid.id,  :method => :post,  :remote => true %></div>

 <% end %>
```

And I have this in videos_controller:

```
  def iframize
   @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
 end
```

And this in routes:

```
 resource :videos do
  collection do
   post 'iframize'
  end
end
```

Problem is that when I click the link, it takes me to

```
http://localhost:3000/videos/iframize?method=post&video_id=20
```

and I get

```
Couldn't find Video with id=iframize
```

I looked through tens of various examples and they seem to recommend the above, but it does not work.. What am I doing wrong?

Any input greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried this approach jquery function and it kinda worked (only for the first video in the loop of course):

```
<% @node.videos.each do |vid| %>
  <%=  image_tag("http://img.youtube.com/vi/#{vid.content}/1.jpg", :id  => 'img_div') %>
<div id="vid_vid"> <%= vid.id %></div>
<% end %>



$('#img_div').on({
  'click': function() {
   var vid_id = document.getElementById("vid_vid").innerHTML;
   $.post("/videos/iframize/", {video_id: vid_id}); 
  }
 });
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your use of link_to is correct. However, the error message indicates that the problem lies in routing, not in the link (which explains the wrong url generated by link_to). Try to run `rake routes` and confirm that the route you want is there. I always use symbols for routes so try switching `post 'iframize'` to `post :iframize`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have rails_ujs included via jquery_ujs in assets/application.css file

```
= link_to image_tag("http://img.youtube.com/vi/#{vid.content}/1.jpg"), "url_path", :method => :post,  :remote => true
```

Convert the following into a rails path: like iframeize_videos_path (generated via `rake routes`)

```
:controller => 'videos', :action => "iframize", :video_id => vid.id,
```

Comment: here is my rake routes:     iframize_videos POST   /videos/iframize(.:format)          {:action=>"iframize", :controller=>"videos"}    when I put "iframize_videos_path" I get to localhost/nodes/iframize_videos

Comment: Oh and, yes I do have jquery_ujs in application.js

Comment: btw, you need to do =link_to image_tag('path'), iframize_videos_path, :remote => true, :video_id => vid.id, :method => :post

Comment: gives same error.. I just tried a jquery hack and it kinda works - I will update the question, maybe it will give some clues.. Thanks a lot for advices!

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate the url options, html options.so use

```
<%= link_to image_tag("http://img.youtube.com/vi/#{vid.content}/1.jpg"), 
{ :controller => 'videos', :action => "iframize", :video_id => vid.id },
{ :method => :post,  :remote => true} %>
```

Comment: try iframize_videos_path(:video_id =>vid.id) instead of { :controller => 'videos', :action => "iframize", :video_id => vid.id }

Comment: same effect.. it's really strange

Comment: Sorry friend I have said possible solutions known to me :(